# Splitting collection into n chunks

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, queue, distributed-computing

I'm currently writing an application that is meant to distribute tasks from `x` master apps instances to `y` workers app instances.

The task data is stored in a MongoDB collection and tasks are queued in a Redis list (rpush + lshift).

The idea is to have the logic follow this cycle:

1. Find `k` new documents from the collection
2. Push them into the queue
3. Shift items that were processed from the queue
4. Based on the results, recreate new documents in the collection
5. Back to 1.

The issue here is in step 1. If there is more than one instance of the master app, the `find()` operation will sometimes return the same results and thus duplicate tasks will be queued in Redis.

I thought about flagging the documents that were queued so as to ignore them in the next queries but the issue is that since MongoDB doesn't have transactions. Those two operations `find()` + `update()` won't be atomic and it's possible in some cases that another instance would `find()` the same documents before the `update()` operation is done.

I know that it is possible to merge both operations with `findAndModify()` but the issue there is that you can only apply this to a single document which is really inefficient. Queuing 100 tasks would mean 100 operations which doesn't seem ideal.

So my question is basically the following:

- Is there a way to split a collection into `n` chunks (one for each master app) or at least block documents from follow-up `find()` operations if another master app returned and queued them already ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't understand step 4: "recreate new documents" - does this just mean `update()`?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the flow of your logic. If a master writes task data to mongo and then puts the task onto the queue (guess you have some id relating the two), then why can't your workers just get a task from the queue and then retrieve the related data from mongo? If a document in mongo only belongs to one task then why should any other worker try to read it?

Comment: @Martin The workers are stateless and not connected to the MongoDB database. The tasks themselves are stored in MongoDB but are pushed to the Redis queue so as to be processed. The tasks are retrieved from MongoDB and can be sent through the queue to any worker app instance.

Comment: @cdbajorin Step 4 is basically recreating new tasks based on the results of the processed task.

Comment: so just to clarify, the only reason you are mentioning `update()` is to talk out the problem, you're not actually updating anything in the flow?

Comment: @m_vdbeek did you find a solution for your problem?